# Area 51 displays badge with docs-beta next to Stack Overflow with missing link

Tags: support, bug, area-51, network-profile, documentation-beta

On [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/96086/paranormal) my badge shows *Documentation Beta reputation* next to *Stack Overflow* (where reputation is exactly the same), therefore it's showing on the top, despite I haven't edited a single page.

[image: Documentation Beta reputation]

Secondly the link points to:

> http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/users/55075

which is redirecting back to *Stack Overflow* user profile.

It's still fine having two of the same badges pointing to the same page, but is it necessary? Is it a bug or a feature? I think the fix would be either to correct the link, or if the documentation is part of *Stack Overflow*, then one icon should be enough, right?